# Project is inactive

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I'm trying to run a very simple project with fastlane and fabric, however, I have the following issue:

```
02:09:19]: Fastlane finished with errors

[!] 2018-08-01 02:09:16.704 submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.5 (18)
2018-08-01 02:09:19.712 submit Crashlytics: Unable to add testers: Project Staging is inactive
2018-08-01 02:09:19.712 submit Crashlytics: Failed to add testers/groups to the release
```

Long story short, I have one react native application that works for iOS and Android. For Android everything is perfect, but for iOS, we need 2 configurations: Production and Staging. Considering that we want to have both applications in the same phone, we need to change the bundle ID. I changed the bundle ID but build process indicates that the Project Staging is inactive.

That is why I created a new application, with the bundle ID `com.*.staging`, and I did all the configuration, however, it doesn't work. I shared the build log and the Fastlane file:

This is the Fastlane file:
https://gist.github.com/cfontana0/1a8b90f09d771f19e9763e334e855106

And this is the log:
https://gist.github.com/cfontana0/c2caf9d39dbd6cd0990f018da48f4e9d

I did all the configuration on the AppDelegate file and I was able to run it on an emulator and a real phone. However, I can't activate the project. I don't know why.

Could you help me?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. You should be all set now. We saw a run of the app, but not a build with Fabric enabled, which prevented the app from activating.